# Tkinter combobox not working when focus_force is called

Tags: python, tkinter

Am trying to select item in my `combobox` but it does not work after i call `focus_force()` on the `toplevel window` other widget in the window works but the `combobox` selection is not working.

When i remove `focus_force()` from my code it works alright but want to keep it for main code.

```
#!python3


import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk



def toplevel_window():
    global top, cb

    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    top.title("TOP")
    top.geometry("300x300")

    cb = ttk.Combobox(top, values=["djdjd", "fjfjf"])
    cb.pack()

    BT = tk.Button(top, text="print", command=combo_select)
    BT.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

    top.bind("<FocusOut>", focusout_func)

    top.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", combo_select)



def focusout_func(event):
    print(cb.get())
    top.focus_force()
    top.bell()



def combo_select(event=None):
    print(cb.get())



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.title("root")


b = tk.Button(text="OPEN TOPLEVEL", command=toplevel_window)
b.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `Combobox` selection is not working is because you're causing the funcion `focusout_func()` to be called when an attempt is made to select it in the window containing it and that shifts the focus back to the toplevel window itself, which prevents the selection from happening.

One solution is simply to not use a `<FocusOut>` callback function at all. Instead, first add a `top.focus_force()` call to the end of `toplevel_window()` function to switch the focus to to it immediately after it's created.

Secondly, to keep the focus on the windows with the `Combobox` and make a bell alert sound when attempts are made to switch focus away from the it, you can `bind` a `<FocusIn>` callback to the `root` window and check the status of the other window in it (and prevent the focus from being changed if it exists and is being displayed).

Here's what I'm suggesting:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from _tkinter import TclError


def toplevel_window():
    global top, cb

    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    top.title("TOP")
    top.geometry("300x300")

    cb = ttk.Combobox(top, values=["djdjd", "fjfjf"])
    cb.pack()

    btn = tk.Button(top, text="print", command=combo_select)
    btn.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

    top.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", combo_select)
    top.focus_force()


def combo_select(event=None):
    print('cb.get():', cb.get())


def root_focusin_callback(event):
    try:
        top_state = top.state()  # Check status of toplevel widget.
    except (NameError, TclError) as exc:
        pass  # Ignore - widget doesn't exist or was closed.
    else:
        top.bell()
        top.focus_force()


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.title("root")

root.bind("<FocusIn>", root_focusin_callback)

b = tk.Button(text="OPEN TOPLEVEL", command=toplevel_window)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i want to call `focusout_func()` to ring bell when root window is clicked when the toplevel is opened.

Comment: i forgot to add `bell()` function to it. check the edit.

Comment: O JOE: That seemingly minor change is actually fairly significant. See the update to my answer.